# how to correct Error parsing data : must begin with JsonObject text '{'"?

Tags: android, getjson, json

EnregistrerActivity.java  – Activity to handle registration event

```
package tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer.UserFunctions;

    import tn.pack.ordre.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class EnregistrerActivity extends Activity {



       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             // Fixe la mise en page d’une activité
            setContentView(R.layout.inscription);

        } 



      public void btn_valider(View v) {     

          String  userName=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un)).getText().toString();
          String  password=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw)).getText().toString();
          String  cin=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cin)).getText().toString();


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(userName,cin,password);
            TextView errorE = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewerrer);

            try {


                if (json.getString("success") != null) {

                    String res = json.getString("success");
                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {

                        errorE.setText("enregistrement ok");


                    } else {
                        errorE.setText("erreur pendant l'enregistrement");


                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("btnRegister:  "+e.toString());
            }


         }

      public void Annuler(View v) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));

                       }
    }
```

UserFunctions.java -In this class all the functions will interact with JSONParser

```
package tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/index.php";
    private static String registerURL = loginURL;

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }


    public JSONObject loginUser(String userName, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", userName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);

        return json;
    }


    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param userName
     * @param cin
     * @param password
     * */

    public JSONObject registerUser(String userName, String cin,String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", userName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cin", cin));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);

        // return json
        return json;
    }


}
```

JSONParser.java -to parse api response JSON.

```
package tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    } 

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

errer logCat :
**E/JSON Parser(261)**

```
    05-22 09:28:44.699: E/Buffer Error(261): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-22 09:28:44.708: E/JSON Parser(261): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of...
    05-22 09:28:44.750: E/AndroidRuntime(261): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer.EnregistrerActivity.btn_valider(EnregistrerActivity.java:45)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  ... 23 more
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  ... 27 more
    05-22 09:37:39.449: E/Buffer Error(354): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-22 09:37:39.449: E/JSON Parser(354): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
    05-22 09:37:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(354): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer.EnregistrerActivity.btn_valider(EnregistrerActivity.java:39)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  ... 23 more
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:60)
    05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  ... 27 more
05-22 09:37:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  ... 27 more
05-22 09:37:39.539: I/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 354 SIG: 3
05-22 09:37:39.539: I/dalvikvm(354): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-22 09:37:39.709: I/dalvikvm(354): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-22 09:37:42.819: I/Process(354): Sending signal. PID: 354 SIG: 9
05-22 09:37:42.869: I/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{44e2a0e0 tn.pack.ordre/tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer.EnregistrerActivity paused=false}
05-22 09:37:42.869: I/ActivityManager(52): Process tn.pack.ordre (pid 354) has died.
05-22 09:37:42.879: I/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{44e00b30 tn.pack.ordre/tn.pack.ordre.enregistrer.LoginActivity paused=false}
05-22 09:37:42.909: I/ActivityManager(52): Start proc tn.pack.ordre for activity tn.pack.ordre/.enregistrer.LoginActivity: pid=363 uid=10028 gids={3003, 1015}
05-22 09:37:43.119: D/ddm-heap(363): Got feature list request
05-22 09:37:43.189: I/UsageStats(52): Unexpected resume of tn.pack.ordre while already resumed in tn.pack.ordre
05-22 09:37:43.349: D/dalvikvm(363): GC freed 719 objects / 54696 bytes in 72ms
05-22 09:37:45.359: W/InputManagerService(52): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 354 uid 10028
05-22 09:37:45.741: I/ActivityManager(52): Displayed activity tn.pack.ordre/.enregistrer.LoginActivity: 2862 ms (total 2862 ms)
05-22 09:37:46.958: I/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/.Launcher }
05-22 09:37:47.228: W/InputManagerService(52): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44e3eaf8 (uid=10028 pid=363)
05-22 09:37:52.699: D/dalvikvm(111): GC freed 164 objects / 6600 bytes in 140ms
05-22 09:46:00.269: D/dalvikvm(52): GC freed 11198 objects / 572384 bytes in 213ms
05-22 09:56:13.229: D/dalvikvm(52): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
05-22 10:05:11.108: D/dalvikvm(104): GC freed 10860 objects / 507696 bytes in 131ms
```

Comment: try to print your response in log to check whether you are getting the response in JSONObject or not?

Comment: Can you post the expanded trace log for the root cause? `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  / 05-22 09:28:44.798: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  ... 27 more`

Comment: ok ,i post the expanded trace log

Answer (score 1):

That is because of unprintable [UTF BOM bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the beginning of the data stream. For UTF-8 it should be EFBBBFh.

It will be solved when you remove (or skip) those bytes.

Comment: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);`   `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);`   the same problem

Comment: if that doesn't work try to see what you really have using,  
    `int c;  
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {  
      Log.d("Char", String.valueOf((char) c));  
    }`

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of

Comment: if I use reader.skip (3);  this block AVD and the screen stays black

Comment: Did you try to print the data stream into logcat? What was the result?

Comment: there 'are two error: "Buffer Error" and "JSON Parser"  and      it does not have any: Log.d ("Char", String.valueOf ((char) c));   no  errer "Char"                  .If you can help me ,i can put the project .

Comment: I had the same issue with those unprintable characters at the beginning of the data stream. I removed those characters and my issue soved. I think, you have the same problem or you don't have a valid incoming JSON stream.

Comment: I do not know. The DVD becomes slower and there's all the time the same error.   If you want, i can put the project.

Comment: MySQL connection collation : utf8_general_ci and I tried "UTF-8" and "iso-8859-1" but it did not work.  reader.skip (3); Where I put it exactly in the code? `try {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8); reader.skip (3); .....`

Comment: @M BenT, I have built the same example. This line should solve your problem.. `sb.substring(sb.indexOf("{"), sb.lastIndexOf("}") + 1)` Sorry for the delay. But, I work at the daytime.

Comment: not yet it is not working
I did not find a solution and I have not much time.

Comment: @M BenT, it is really curious problem.. Please, write your contact info.